# Find median of a trapezoid if diagonals, which intersect at right angles, are 3 and 4.

Tags: geometry, area

I wrote down similar triangles thing but don't know what to do next. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If nothing, try and apply Pythagoras. If you get stuck, add a diagram along with what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

What we are given.
$AC = 4\\
BD = 3\\
AC\perp BD$

$\triangle ABE\sim \triangle CDE$

$AE = \alpha EC\\ 
BE = \alpha ED\\
AB = \alpha CD$

Because the similar triangles share proportionality.

$AE+EC = AC = 4\\
\alpha EC +EC = 4\\
(1+\alpha) EC = 4$

Similarly, $(1+\alpha) ED = 3$

By Pythagoras $EC^2 + ED^2 = CD^2$

This is enough information to find $CD$ in terms of $\alpha.$  And by the similarity rules find $AB$

The median equals $\frac {1}{2} (AB + CD).$

Hopefully, the $\alpha$'s cancel.

Or, you could consider the degenerate case where $\alpha = 0$ and then decide if this indeed describes the general case.